# R Grep help: match exact substring. RStudio on Mac OSX

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to match an exact substring using grep. I'm using the following expression:

```
grep("^.*apple().*$",inputString)
```

Expected output:

1) input string is `"apple()"` - expected to match

2) input string is `"appleSomethingElse()"` - expected not to match

Case 1 works and I get  a match. However case two also matches. I'm trying to write a regular expression that only matches when "apple" and "()" are next to each other in the string. Is my expression wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to escape (`\\`) the parentheses (`()`) to make this work using the same syntax as in the OP's code.

```
 grep("^.*apple\\(\\).*$", x)
 #[1] 1 3
```

As @DavidArenburg mentioned in the comments, if this is for matching a string instead of substring, `==` would be more useful.

```
 x=='apple()'
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

#### data

```
x <- c('apple()', 'appleSomethingElse()', 'adadaapple()aaa')
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't know what kind of strings the OP has.  Perhaps he has `apple() something` or `something apple()`.  In that case, the exact matching won't work.  Also he mentions `match an exact substring` instead of `match an exact string`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, that should work too.  But, I was trying to fix the OP's present code.

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I was trying to match the exact substring. It was the escaping of the parentheses I needed to add.

Answer (score 4):

When, you have [metacharacters](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) in your expression that you want to match, you can simply use the `fixed = TRUE` argument within `grep` and thus leave your expression simple.

```
x <- c('apple()', 'appleSomethingElse()', 'adadaapple()aaa')
grep('apple()', x, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] 1 3
```